# How to upload files to custom folder in AppEngine with blobstore and google cloud storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I am using Google AppEngine. I am using the blobstore to upload files to Google Cloud Storage. (I can't upload to Cloud Storage directly because of request size restriction of AppEngine.)

I could upload to Google Cloud Storage. But I couldn't specify the folder to upload. So every file is being stored in the root folder.

Can anybody tell me how to upload to a specific folder?

I use the code from https://github.com/crhym3/java-blobstore-gcs-sample

Comment: did you try to set `.withGoogleStorageBucketName` with `bucketname/folder` value?

Comment: ok, that was just in case it works :)

Comment: sorry, the 400 was with something else. now it works. If you put it as an answer I could accept it. Thank you very much

Comment: "I can't upload to Cloud Storage directly because of request size restriction of AppEngine"   -  You can upload files up to 5GB in size to Cloud Storage directly. App Engine has nothing to do with direct uploads.

Comment: but inorder to do direct upload, we need to provide security headers and other things right (authorization)? I want to upload without any explicit authorization from user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It comes out that you can pass a "*folder*" name with a bucket name into `.withGoogleStorageBucketName()` method, like:

```
UploadOptions uploadOptions = UploadOptions.Builder
     .withGoogleStorageBucketName("bucket_name/folder_name");
```